# If p(x) is a non-negative quadratic polynomial, p(0)=8 and p(8)=0, what is p(-4)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> A quadratic polynomial $p(x)$ is such that $p(x)$ never takes any negative values. Also, $p(0)=8$ and $p(8)=0$. What would $p(-4)$ be?

I tried doing it by taking the minimum value as zero that is the vertex of the polynomial at $8$. How do we go about after finding out values of $a$ and $b$ in the standard form of the equation $ax^2 + bx + c$ ? Could this be done in a shorter way graphically?

Comment: If $p(x)$ never takes any negative values, wouldn't $p(-4)$ be undefined? Or invalid?

Comment: @BrianJ I think he means $p(x) \geq 0 \forall x$.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way to solve this without needing as much mathematical insight as Barry's answer. If the polynomial is $$p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c,$$ then from $p(0) = 8$ we get $$0a + 0b + c=8,$$ from $p(8) = 0$ we get $$64a + 8b + c = 0,$$ and from $p(x)$ never taking any negative values, it follows that $x=8$ is a minimum, and so $p′(8) = 0$, and since $p′(x) = 2ax + b$, then we get $$16a + b + 0c = 0.$$ This gives three simultaneous equations in three variables, which give the coefficients $$a={1\over 8}, b=-2, c=8.$$

Answer (score 21):

Since $p(x)$ is always non-negative, and $p(8) = 0$, it follows that that must be the vertex. The standard form for a parabola is $a(x-h)^2 + k$, and we already know that $(h,k)$ is $(8,0)$. That gives us $p(x) = a(x-8)^2$.

Now simply plug in $p(0) = 8$ to get $a = \frac{1}{8}$ to find $p$:

$$p(x) = \frac{1}{8}(x-8)^2$$

So:

$$p(-4) = 18$$